# Visual Studio Community 2022 perfomance profiler doesn't show queries

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

Why this queries panel didn't show any query that EF executes? I have executed my application and events have been executed that run queries with EF, I don't understand why no information is being shown.

I commented these lines

[image]

updated Visual Studio, and I have investigated to see what else I can do but nothing has worked.